# Standalone Flash Pepper on 14.04?

Tags: flash

Is there a Standalone Flash Pepper version available out there?
Or would it be possible to execute the chrome plugin without running chrome?
Thanks :-)

Comment: [Can I use Chrome's Pepper Flash with Firefox?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/562271/can-i-use-chromes-pepper-flash-with-firefox/562272#562272) has an answer for getting Chrome's plugin working with Firefox, such that you won't need to actually open Google Chrome to use it.

Comment: It seems to be a solution for using Firefox. I would be interested in a stand alone flash player solution.

Comment: okay, I misunderstood.  That point not withstanding, there is no Pepper Flash standalone for Linux - only the Adobe standalones for Windows.  HOWEVER, I would point out that the Adobe Standalone versions [for Windows run perfectly fine under Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=30941) without the need to install Flash for Linux.  (Which fails miserably when you try and use it, because it's Flash 11, not Flash 15 or 16(beta).)

Comment: There is actually a Linux Projector https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html but it stopped support at flash v11.2. That is why I am interested in Pepper Flash which support latest features.

Comment: I changed my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I could tell (and I scoured Google to try and find an answer for this, and didn't find one even 15 pages in), ***there is no standalone runtime / projector / player for Pepper Flash.***

**However**, as an alternative, you could use the [Flash 15 Standalone Player executable for Windows](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/15/flashplayer_15_sa.exe)<sub>([AppDB Entry](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=30941))</sub> (or even the [Flash 16 beta Standalone Player executable for Windows](http://labsdownload.adobe.com/pub/labs/flashruntimes/flashplayer/flashplayer16_sa_win_32.exe)<sub>([AppDB Entry](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=31271))</sub>) within Wine.  I have tested this (on both of them), and it seems to work smoothly and without issues.  In fact, I've noticed it runs FAR smoother than Firefox or Chrome's flash plugins does.  It is a usable alternative until there is a Pepper Flash standalone (if there ever is, as all I could find was Pepper Flash is provided by Adobe to Google under license.)

Adobe also made a Flash 11 standalone player for Linux, but it is still Flash 11, and it is really buggy and crashed for me every time I tried to use it in Ubuntu 14.04.  That's why I went the "Windows Standalone Flash Inside of Wine" route, which seems to work.

---

> NOTE: Yes, the links don't work - it's too hard to play catchup every time Flash updates.  Use [this link](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) always to find the 'latest' versions that Adobe makes available.

Comment: I will give it a try, do you think this could impact performance?

Comment: @mika I have yet to see a performance decrease (It WON'T work in a browser though, as it's standalone). In fact, I see a performance *increase* compared to the browser-shipped Flash.  However, the trade off is slightly higher CPU cycles and your graphics card being used a bit more. I still think it's a suitable alternative to waiting for a Pepper Flash standalone.  (The only thing is, just like Windows, you'll need to tweak the security settings to let it reach out to the internet if it needs internet features. That's just like Windows though, and just like the Flash plugin for Firefox, too.)

Comment: I wonder how it will compare in term of performance to the latest Linux Air v2.6

Comment: @mika Air doesn't work for everything, you know.  It's not a full Flash replacement.

Comment: Actually, isn't Air a flash wrapper with an extended AS3 API?

Comment: @mika "Adobe Flash Player is a browser plug-in that provides advantages for users and content creators in the browser, including the ability to deliver RIAs in the browser. AIR incorporates technologies originally developed in Flash Player and enables RIAs on the desktop. AIR and Flash Player provide complementary deployment methods for RIAs." (http://www.adobe.com/products/air/faq.html).  I don't think AIR can play SWF out of the box though.  Note that AIR for Linux is **also** unsupported now (same FAQ document)

Comment: These comments are misleading from my original question. And yes Air can load swf files and execute them, unless on iOS.

Comment: @mika According to what I found, it can run them, but it *can't* access the local filesystem.  Therefore, if you want AIR to run all your Flash applications and it in turn has other SWF dependencies on the local disk, I believe you might run into problems.

Comment: I am intending to use it headless to render swf content to video using sockets instead of file system. I already have a working air pipeline set up but it is relying on Air 2.5 which is equivalent to flash 10. I am trying to find a solution that allows me to use the latest flash player.

Comment: @mika there is no solution if you want the latest Flash - Air was discontinued for Linux and so was Flash, either use Pepper Flash in the browser or the standalone one, but the issue still remains of security settings - you're kind of out of luck right now

Comment: Security is not a concern since it is running in a restricted ip network and the loaded content is trusted. So back to my question then :) is there a stand alone version of Pepper to run chrome-less and head-less?

Comment: @mika have you actually read my answer saying that there is not?

Comment: i don't take no for an answer :) But thank you!

Comment: The links to download the standalone playersd don't seem to work anymore. Trying http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/16/flashplayer_16_sa.exe right now.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like pipelight

     `sudo apt-get install pipelight`

`pipelight-plugin --enable flash`

This has the advantage of also supporting unity3d and silverlight if you enable them, and should be up to date, as it runs flash through wine.

Comment: Thanks! When running sudo apt-get install pipelight-multi ttf-mscorefonts-installer defoma I get the following E: Package 'defoma' has no installation candidate

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the missing font error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431470/install-mscorefonts-on-ec2?noredirect=1#comment43906564_27431470

Comment: Thanks for the resource, although this is not a standalone solution since it requires a browser.