# Latest Flash Player last for linux per Adobe. Any substitutes in the works?

Tags: flash, adobe

Adobe announcement on the download site.

"NOTE: Adobe Flash Player 11.2 will be the last version to target Linux as a supported platform. Adobe will continue to provide security backports to Flash Player 11.2 for Linux."

Has Adobe threatened this before?

Any Ubuntu official substitutes in the works?
[Will check Flash tag for alternatives, but thought I should raise a flag.]

Comment: This type of question should be posted [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/597941/shockwave-flash-17-0-for-linux.     Sorry, I missed that the answer, for now, is supplied in the answers to this question.  I hope a simpler way will emerge. Unfortunately as long as Adobe holds copyright and patents[?] we are in the soup, so to speak.

Comment: Thank you, I will look and ask if needed there. Although It is sort of a situation related to not just to Linux but all three: Ubuntu, Linux, and Firefox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get latest Flash player on Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/524279/get-latest-flash-player-on-ubuntu)