# How to pick a launcher to install software

Tags: software-installation

New to Ubuntu 14.04. Want to install adobe flash plug-in which I picked from the Ubuntu Software Center. After clicking on Install I have a choice of what application I want to use. When I choose the appropriate software i.e. (APT for Ubuntu 10.4+) the System is asking what launcher I will use to install. I have no clue what to answer/pick. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Open a terminal with Ctrl-Alt-T and run `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are referring to this thing [here](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/):
[image: Flash player downloads page]

You are right in that you pick the APT deb package. What you can do with is download it, and open it in Software Center - other methods are available for installing deb packages via the command line, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/40779/178596).

Ubuntu (and most Linux systems), usually does not require you to download random software off the internet. Verified packages are available from the Ubuntu repositories, which can be downloaded and installed from Software Center, `apt-get`, `aptitude` etc *(other packages are also available via [PPAs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them))*. They also receive updates with the rest of the system, so overall this is the best method to use. For Flash just install the `flashplugin-installer` package.

By the way the NPAPI version of flash for Linux (and other non-Windowz/Mac systems) is only available as the old 11 release (excuse from Adobe is they are *apparently* getting rid of flash player). It works and is supposed to have security backports - if you want the new version you can use Google Chrome (or Chromium and `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` package) to get PPAPI flash which still receives updates. This can be used with Firefox as well via the use of a plugin adapter - see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562271/can-i-use-chromes-pepper-flash-with-firefox)