# firefox - this browser does not support video playback

Tags: firefox, flash

I have problem watching twitter embedded videos. I got this error message: "This browser does not support video playback."

[Here is an example](https://twitter.com/TeslaMotors/status/676125794121474048)

[image]

I have Firefox version 43.0.

Comment: Try `wget http://bit.ly/1Oq3FNN -O Tesla.mp4` see if you can play the video on your desktop.

Comment: @Alex I could watch the downloaded file with firefox - gecko player

Comment: Do you have flash installed? I was able to watch in my firefox.

Comment: @Muzaffar I dont think that is flash. But i have it anyway. I have adblock blugin but even it is disabled I got this error.

Comment: @laplasz It requires either latest flash or HTML5 afaik

Comment: @Parto Are there any related errors/warnings in the browser's web console? (You can open it by going to Tools -> Web Developer -> Web Console. You also need to refresh the page after you open to see if there's any issue)

Answer (score 9):

You should -

1. make sure that gstreamer1.0-libav plugin is installed
2. then in firefox address bar go `about:config`, search `mediasource` & enable
   `media.mediasource.webm.enabled` &  `media.mediasource.enabled`

That should allow playback on twitter as long as the 1st. 2 mentioned below are **not enabled** or **you enable all 3**

If you want full coverage in Firefox as seen in https://www.youtube.com/html5, (all 6),  then in about:config in addition to above search `media` & enable
`media.fragmented-mp4.exposed` & `media.fragmented-mp4.ffmpeg.enabled` & needed to not break facebook `media.fragmented-mp4.gmp.enabled`

As they say proof is in the pudding -

[image]

Comment: Aren't media.mediasource.webm.enabled & media.mediasource.enabled enabled by default? Mine are and I don't recall changing them.

Comment: They are in 43 but not in 42. Whether when upgrading they get enabled not sure, will ck. in 16.04. The other issue could be that if one enabled the other mentioned for full mediasource support for youtube then it breaks that facebook thing if the gmp on isn't enabled, at least as seen here.

Comment: Ok, just checked in 16.04. When upgrading to 43 your existing profile does get those 2 enabled. So the issue for Parto could be, not on 43, some errant plugin/ext. or that he/she has those other ones enabled that break facebook. Here it had nothing to do with other plugins/ext., simply as described above to get rid of the not supported, ect.

Comment: Interesting. Checked mine in 14.04 and they were enabled by default.

Comment: fixed it for me in 15.10

Comment: Just to note - I believe in the latest firefox versions gst plugins are no longer used, in that case the above answer is moot as far as the libav plugin

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Pepper Flash` in `firefox`. `Pepper Flash` is basically Chrome's Flash API. Chrome has this API installed by default (You might notice this when you have a fresh install of Windows/Linux and Chrome doesn't need to install flash while other browsers do).

Here are the steps:

1. Open terminal by clicking the Ubuntu logo, the Super key or press Ctrl+Alt+T
2. Type or copy in

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install freshplayerplugin
```

3. Install `google-chrome` from it's website or use the `chromium` way in the link below (The reason you install Google Chrome is for the `freshplayerplugin` to recognize the Pepper Flash in Chrome and load it into Firefox)

Open `firefox` and go to `about:plugins`. This is what you should get (notice the flash version):
[image: about:plugins]

Uninstall Linux Flash by doing

```
sudo apt-get purge flashplugin-installer adobe-flashplugin adobe-flash-properties-gtk adobe-flash-properties-kde
```

Source: [Can I use Chrome's Pepper Flash with Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562271/can-i-use-chromes-pepper-flash-with-firefox)

Comment: Still facing the same issue - 'This browser does not support video playback.' This is my test link: https://twitter.com/KenyanTraffic/status/689330954071076864

Comment: @Parto do `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` and do `sudo apt-get purge flashplugin-installer adobe-flashplugin` after that.

Comment: Oh and just for sure you can install Java by doing `sudo apt-get install icedtea-plugin`

Comment: I already have `ubuntu-restricted-extras` and already purged `flas-plugin`

Comment: @Parto How about Java? Anyway try to install this extension (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher-firefox/?src=search) and change the UA to Chrome.

Comment: Doesn't work either.

Comment: @Parto so you've tried the UA method and it still doesn't work? Try different UA like Chrome or Opera.

Answer (score 1):

I have just updated Firefox to version 43.0 and now the video is supported and playable.

Comment: I'm running FF 43.0 on Ubuntu 14.04, and I've applied all available updates, but I still have this issue.

Comment: Firefox 43.04 also has this issue with the adblock plugin installed.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is definitely add-on/extension related.

**Restarting with add-ons disabled in Firefox safe mode** resolves the issue. Note that simply disabling or removing ad block plus does not work. How: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode

In my case I had flashblock installed and disabling it from firefox addon manager did the trick. as seen below:

[image: flashblock-disable]

Sources: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode

Testing

Comment: Same case here. I had installed flash-block. Is there a way to have flash block enabled on other sites but disabled on twitter only, whitelisting doesn't work.

Comment: Got it, add the following url in the whitelist of flashblock `amg.twimg.com`

Comment: @Parto the whitelisting of `amg.twimg.com` didn't work for me when visiting https://twitter.com/TeslaMotors/status/676125794121474048 as linked in the OP question. Rolling back edit.