# Websites erroneously believe I don't have Flash installed

Tags: graphics, video, flash, streaming, firefox-extensions

With Firefox, I have been to a number of websites, such as Hulu, for video streaming that return an error message that I don't have Flash installed. Well, of course I do. I can play YouTube videos fine. Hulu is a special case which also reports that I cannot play protected content, which may be a separate issue, but then it also states, erroneously, that I need to install Flash. How can this be resolved?

As requested in comments here is the output of `apt-cache search adobe flash`

```
texlive-latex-extra - TeX Live: LaTeX additional packages
flashplugin-installer - Adobe Flash Player plugin installer
flashplugin-downloader - Adobe Flash Player plugin installer (transitional package)
flashplugin-nonfree-extrasound - Adobe Flash Player platform support library for Esound and OSS
bleachbit - delete unnecessary files from the system
cclive - lightweight command line video extraction tool
konqueror-nsplugins - Netscape plugin support for Konqueror
libjs-swfobject - tool to embed Flash content into webpages
libquvi-dev - library for parsing video download links (development package)
libquvi-doc - library for parsing video download links (documentation package)
libquvi-scripts - library for parsing video download links (Lua scripts)
libquvi7 - library for parsing video download links (runtime libraries)
libvdpau-va-gl1 - VDPAU driver with OpenGL/VAAPI backend
nomnom - download videos from Youtube and other similar video websites
quvi - command line program to extract video download links
red5-doc - flash streaming server - documentation
red5-server - flash streaming server
adobe-flashplugin - Adobe Flash Player plugin
adobe-flash-properties-gtk - GTK+ control panel for Adobe Flash Player plugin
adobe-flash-properties-kde - KDE control panel Adobe Flash Player plugin
```

System Info:

- The `universe` distribution component is **enabled** for all sources.
- Flash plugin enabled in Firefox: Shockwave flash 11.2 r202 and 13.1
  r2
- 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04.4
- *Hardware* (in case it matters): 
      * Acer Aspire laptop
      * AMD A6-1450 APU w/ Radeon HD Graphics × 4
      * Gallium 0.4 on AMD KABINI

Comment: did you make universe repository enabled?if not run this `sudo add-apt-repository universe` .Then from the cache try to see what u have `apt-cache search adobe flash`.Put the output here please

Comment: Adobe flash is no longer supported on Ubuntu AFAIK... Have you tried pepper flash via Google Chrome?

Comment: @Tim I would like to keep using Firefox if possible.

Comment: @gracious1 If you could try with chrome that may help debug. If it's not installed do not worry. :-)

Comment: @Tim Ok, post as answer b/c comments are getting too long, and I will pursue this.

Comment: @gracious1 @Tim me when you have done it. We will move to chat when the system says to :)`

Comment: @Tim Do we Chrome or will Chromium do? I have the latter installed already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38142/discussion-between-tim-and-gracious1).

Answer (score 0):

You have html5 plugin for firefox installed, which allows watching youtube videos, but sites like hulu do require flash.  You can verify that if you go to `about:config` and then Plugins in firefox, OpenH264 is what you're looking for

To install flash , run `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`, but keep in mind that the latest version is 11.2.577 and Adobe removed support for Linux version of flash like since last year and it won't be supported anymore.

Note that you must have multiverse repository  enabled in System Settings -> Software & Updates

Alternatively, switch to pepper flash in Chrome

Comment: Is there something like pepper-flash that I can install on Firefox? As stated in earlier comments I would prefer to keep using Firefox.

Comment: `flashplugin-installer` is installed from the partner repository which is not enabled by default, please include instructions for enabling this repository.

Comment: @gracious1: I'm pretty sure that that Chrome plugin only exists because Google and Adobe have a partnership, Google and Mozilla have no such partnership so Mozilla is not allowed to ship the latest version of the Adobe Flash plugin in its browser.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I've added mention of the multiverse repository. It's not necessary to list all the steps, because it's quite obvious

Comment: @gracious1 there is a way http://askubuntu.com/q/562271/295286 But I've never tried it, so can't say how that works

Comment: @ParanoidPanda, the Windows versions of Firefox get the latest Flash. It's only Linux that's screwed :(