# My HP laptop will not allow a flash player to work (play games) what software do i need?

Tags: software-installation

I try to go onto gameing sites and it will come u[ i need the latest version of ADOBE but i have tried to download multiply Adobe programs and nothing successful  PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use Chrome's Pepper Flash with Firefox?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/562271/can-i-use-chromes-pepper-flash-with-firefox)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Mozilla Firefox as your browser. I had the same problem. Dont worry just download Google Chrome and set it as your default browser and Adobe flash should work

Google Chrome :https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/

Comment: ubuntu software centre wont install , says unstable etc. please help driving me nuts

Comment: @T.Gunn - What error are you getting?