# Ubuntu 16 won't play youtube videos, sometimes

Tags: 16.04, firefox, youtube

youtube.com/html5 is enabled.

I am using the latest flashplayer I can find for Ubuntu 16.

I only get this error `(process:9281): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_path_get_basename: assertion 'file_name != NULL' failed`

I tried starting Firefox in safe mode.

It works when I restart the computer completely, but then after some time playing videos, it fails on me. It stops playing altogether, and when I click on a new video, even after `killall firefox` and restarting `firefox`, it only shows one or two frames from the video and won't progress at all.

I'm really not sure how to debug this at all. Thanks in advance.

Some updates:

```
 firefox

(process:9169): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_path_get_basename: assertion 'file_name != NULL' failed

(process:9281): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_path_get_basename: assertion 'file_name != NULL' failed
^C[Child 9281] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file /build/firefox-6p7T67/firefox-48.0+build2/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp, line 2046
[Child 9281] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file /build/firefox-6p7T67/firefox-48.0+build2/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp, line 2046

[1]+  Terminated              firefox
~/Programming/hap$ firefox

(process:9528): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_path_get_basename: assertion 'file_name != NULL' failed
NOT SANDBOXED
[fresh  9561] not implemented: PPB_FileRef;1.2
[fresh  9561] not implemented: PPB_OpenGLES2VertexArrayObject;1.0
[fresh  9561] not implemented: PPB_OpenGLES2DrawBuffers(Dev);1.0
Vector smash protection is enabled.
[fresh  9561] not implemented: PPB_BrokerTrusted;0.3
[fresh  9561] [PPB] {zilch} ppb_network_monitor_update_network_list
[fresh  9561] [PPB] {zilch} ppb_flash_set_instance_always_on_top instance=11, on_top=1
[fresh  9561] not implemented: PPB_BrokerTrusted;0.3
[fresh  9561] [PPB] {zilch} ppb_network_monitor_update_network_list
[fresh  9561] [PPB] {zilch} ppb_flash_set_instance_always_on_top instance=12, on_top=1
[fresh  9561] not implemented: PPB_BrokerTrusted;0.3
[fresh  9561] [PPB] {zilch} ppb_network_monitor_update_network_list
[fresh  9561] [PPB] {zilch} ppb_flash_set_instance_always_on_top instance=13, on_top=1
[fresh  9561] not implemented: PPB_BrokerTrusted;0.3
[fresh  9561] [PPB] {zilch} ppb_network_monitor_update_network_list
".ARNING:flash/platform/pepper/pep_url_request_info.cpp(219)] Missing colon in HTTP header line "
```

I suspect this is a problem with freshplayer wrapping pepperflash.

Comment: What is your system's configuration

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "system's configuration"?

Comment: Processor, graphics card, etc.

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with it. AMD Athlon X4, Asus Radeon R9 270X, Gigabyte GA-F2A88X-D3H ATX FM2+

Comment: I can suggest you try a live CD and see if everything works. If it does, reinstall.

Comment: Why did you add your answer inside your question? Please post a self-answer instead.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I am still testing it to see if it worked. It's now unclear if the issue is Bluetooth related or what... Strange behavior today.

Answer (score 1):

The follow appears to have worked for me:

[Can I use Chrome's Pepper Flash with Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562271/can-i-use-chromes-pepper-flash-with-firefox)

```
sudo aptitude --purge-unused purge flashplugin-installer adobe-flashplugin adobe-flash-properties-gtk adobe-flash-properties-kde browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
```